# Central limit theorem for minimum

Tags: normal-distribution, convergence, central-limit-theorem

Suppose I have two sequences of random variables, $\overline{X}_1(n)$ and $\overline{X}_2(n)$, and two parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, such that the below convergence in distribution holds (jointly):

$$(\sqrt{n} (\overline{X}_1(n)-\theta_1),\sqrt{n} (\overline{X}_2(n)-\theta_2)) \xrightarrow{d} (G_1,G_2)$$

where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are $N(0,1)$ variables which may, or may not, be correlated with one another. Is it true that:

$$\sqrt{n} (\min(\overline{X}_1(n),\overline{X}_2(n))-\min(\theta_1,\theta_2)) \xrightarrow{d} \min(G_1,G_2)$$

---

Update: Someone edited my question and put:

> Answer: The above statement is false.

Why is this? Please could someone clarify? Maybe provide a counter example?

Comment: Given you state you have just *two* random variables, what exactly is happening to create a limit in distribution??  What do your parameters represent--means or something else?  Are you--as the notation might suggest--considering *sequences* of random variables?  If so, what independence assumptions might you be making? I'm sure all this is obvious to you, but we shouldn't take any of it for granted, because the possibility of constructing counterexamples might rely on *exactly* what assumptions you are making.

Comment: Apologies you are right, I neglected the subscript $n$'s. I will fix my notation and phrasing!

Comment: What do you mean by the 'min' operator? You also apply it to the parameters $\theta_i$, why is that?

Comment: @Sextus This is a perfectly conventional use of "$\min$"!  Specifically, "$\min(X,Y)$" is the composition of the function $\min :\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ with the bivariate random variable $(X,Y):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^2$ while "$\min(\theta_1,\theta_2)$" is a direct application of that function to an element of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: Maybe we could write it more simple by getting rid of the $\theta_i$ and $\sqrt{n}$ and state: suppose we have for $n \to \infty$ that

$$X_1(n),X_2(n) \xrightarrow{d} G_1,G_2 \qquad \text{with $G_i \sim N(0,1)$}$$

do we also have 

$$min(X_1(n),X_2(n)) \xrightarrow{d} min(G_1,G_2)$$

Comment: I agree @whuber that it is a conventional use. But in the *way* that it is applied I wonder whether it was intended like that. I do not get the logic of the application.

Comment: @Sextus Agreed.  Your simplification is a useful improvement of the question--but it's not exactly the same as the question, because it implicitly supposes that $\min$ enjoys a kind of linearity property.

Comment: We only have $$min(X_1-\theta_1,X_2-\theta_2) \sim min(X_1,X_2) - min(\theta_1,\theta_2)$$ in special cases. I am not sure whether the question is about that or whether it is a mistake.

Comment: @Sextus Yes, that's what it appears to come down to.

Comment: Assuming the "joint" convergence in distribution into a multi-variate normal, then I think we have these results: 1) when $\theta_1 = \theta_2$, the statement is true, per Slutsky's Theorem as min() is a continuous mapping from $R^2$ into $R^1$; 2) when $\theta_1 \ne \theta_2$, from the Delta Method, we should still converge to a univariate normal, and thus the statement is generally false.

Comment: @ShangZhang Slutsky's theorem requires one of the variables to converge to a constant. This is important because it guarantees convergence to a joint distribution. In the question statement it is not clear what joint distribution the variables converge to. The correlation between variables is important. If we happen to have $X_1 = -X_2$ then the result is different from the situation $X_1 = X_2$.

Comment: Indeed, nothing in the question implies the variables must converge to a bivariate Normal variable!  BTW, it's hard to see how one would justify applying the delta method to a nondifferentiable function: that's going to take some care.

Comment: But if the question is meant to be that the distribution converges to a specific *joint* distribution, then the continuous mapping theorem should work (I guess it applies to the multivariate case as well).

Comment: My thinking was; let $\mathbf{\bar{X}(n)}=[\bar{X}_1(n),\bar{X}_2(n)]'$, $\mathbf{\theta}=[\theta_1,\theta_2]'$ and $\mathbf{G}=[G_1,G_2]'$. We have: $$\sqrt{n}(\mathbf{\bar{X}(n)}-\mathbf{\theta})\xrightarrow{d}\mathbf{G}.$$ Think of $\min$ as a function of $\mathbf{v}=[v_1,v_2]'\in\mathbb{R}^2$ which is differentiable everywhere except where $v_1=v_2$. By delta method, on any region where $\theta_1\neq \theta_2$ the result holds true. I'm not sure for the regions where $\theta_1=\theta_2$...

Comment: But if that argument is correct I am really surprised it couldn't be shown by directly substituting in $min(a,b)=\frac{a+b−|a−b|}{2}$